# Omnet++ make issues

Tags: omnet++

I get the following error when compiling omnetpp-5.4.1, do I need to uninstall the libgles2-mesa-dev package ?

In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:

> `/usr/include/GL/glext.h:469:19: error: typedef redefinition with different types
>         ('ptrdiff_t' (aka 'int') vs 'khronos_intptr_t' (aka 'long'))
>   typedef ptrdiff_t GLintptr;
>                     ^
>   /usr/include/GLES3/gl31.h:74:26: note: previous definition is here
>   typedef khronos_intptr_t GLintptr;
>                            ^
>   In file included from osgviewer.cc:27:
>   In file included from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions:1:
>   /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtGui/qopenglfunctions.h:60:16: error: 
>         cannot combine with previous 'double' declaration specifier
>   typedef double GLdouble;
>                  ^
>   /usr/include/osg/GL:129:38: note: expanded from macro 'GLdouble'
>                       #define GLdouble double
>                                        ^
>   3 errors generated.`

Comment: On what platform/distro/os version you are compiling OMNeT++?

Comment: Platform - Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+, OS - Raspberry Pi 4.9.80-v7+

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the system headers. If you do not need OpenSceneGraph/osgEarth support, you can turn it off in the `configure.user` file and the re-configure/rebuild omnet. That will exclude the OSG specific files from the build process. (if you do not need the graphical environment (Qtenv) you can even turn off that in the `configure.user` which will prevent also linking with Qt libs).

Comment: I turned off OpenSceneGraph/osgEarth  in configure.user, now the below error is thrown***
===== Compiling opp_run ====
Creating executable: /home/pi/Downloads/omnetpp-5.4.1/out/clang-release/src/envir/opp_run
/home/pi/Downloads/omnetpp-5.4.1/lib/liboppsim.so: undefined reference to `__mulodi4'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Makefile:118: recipe for target '/home/pi/Downloads/omnetpp-5.4.1/out/clang-release/src/envir/opp_run' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/pi/Downloads/omnetpp-5.4.1/out/clang-release/src/envir/opp_run] Error 1